# Backgroundworker - UI still not responsive until BGW completed

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, winforms, backgroundworker

I implemented a BGW to my application in hopes of speeding up loading time for the starting window(40+ controls)

I will not post my whole code as it's far too long but will give you the gist of the code.  I split big function calls that take time to complete alongwith a handful of controls and moved them into the BGW in hopes of asyncronously loading controls to help quicken the process.

It is understood that I have to move UI changing code to the ProgressChanged event or RunWorkerCompleted event, which I have done.  I originally had all code thrown into the DoWork event and it was extremely fast but found out it's not safe so I had reworked it to move all UI-related oode to the ProgressChanged.  It's not nearly as fast now and it seems that the BGW controls wait until the UI thread completes prior to changing the controls in the BGW_ProgressCHanged event.  I never saw this 'lag' between the two when I had all the changes in DoWork.  What can I do about this?  Or can I at least had the BGW update the controls realtime rather than waiting for all controls are completed before updating all controls?

The responsiveness is lower as well as it locks up the window to wait for the BGW controls to update.  Just looking for what could possibly be happening

```
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
SyncLock <globalVar>
                    BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0, "Tom")

End SyncLock
End Sub

 Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged
  Dim value As String = DirectCast(e.UserState, String)
 Select Case e.ProgressPercentage

Case 0 
 lblName.text = value
 lblName.Visible = true
End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: You have a `SyncLock` on an object. The UI thread would be blocked if it also attempts to lock that object while the `BackgroundWorker` is running.

Comment: I was under the impression that SyncLock would be the only way to use a shared global variable in another thread safely.  Is there a better way?

Comment: Don't allow the `BackgroundWorker` to access that variable at all. Return the result and update the variable in the `RunWorkerCompleted` event handler.

Comment: I am trying to understand.  I have all logic for all controls in the BGW_DoWork event, in order to use that logic i need to use that variable which can only be declared once throughout the project.

Comment: The `BackgroundWorker` can operate on a copy of the variable. You can also just try to minimize the scope of the lock to statements where it's actually accessed instead of locking it for the entire `DoWork` event handler.

Comment: When you say Copy of the variable, is this with some other functionality than SyncLock to do this?  I will try to not include SyncLock over all the statements, thanks!

Comment: I'm starting to think that what you really want to do is run multiple short operations in parallel. BackgroundWorker won't do that for you. Unless of course you create a new worker for every operation. Does that sound about right?

Answer (score 2):

You removed all evidence of the problem in your code, but the diagnostic is an excellent match.  You have a **fire hose** problem.  Your code is calling ReportProgress far too often.

Things go wrong when your ProgressChanged event handler needs *more* time than the time between ReportProgress calls.  Which is like drinking from a fire hose, no matter how fast you swallow the water, you just can't keep up with the flow.

Which is what the UI thread experiences.  When it finishes the call to your ProgressChanged event handler, there's yet more water, yet another request to call the handler.  That relentlessly continues without the UI thread ever being able to keep up.  It now doesn't get around to doing its normal duties anymore.  Which means that your UI stops updating, paints are no longer performed.  And it doesn't respond to input anymore.

This can last for a while *after* the worker thread stopped running, the UI is still trying to work down the backlog of requests.  When it finally gets there, the UI suddenly springs back to life.

A simple way to diagnose this condition is to add this method call after the ReportProgress call:

```
   System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(45)
```

Which slows down the worker thread enough to limit the number of ReportProgress() calls to no more than 21 per second.  Which is plenty fast enough for human eyes, anything faster just looks like a blur so is wasted effort.  If that fixes the problem then you found the cause.

Using Sleep() like this is otherwise an ugly Q&D solution for the problem, it of course also slows down your worker so its gets less work done.  You'll have to improve your code so that this doesn't happen and just makes less ReportProgress calls.

Comment: Thanks for the information!  I will attempt this, is there a better, more efficient way to go about doing this with a backgroundworker? I feel calling the ProgressChanged many times for each component wasn't the best way to do it and not intended in this way.

Comment: This always works much better if you *first* try the suggestions, then think about what you are going to do with what you found out.  "Is there a better way" is unanswerable without me knowing *anything* about your code.

Comment: I did try your suggestion and I didn't see a change in quickness.  So i suspect it's some underlying issue.  I will continue searching, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

One thing you might want to add before starting the worker:

```
    Me.SuspendLayout()
```

Then, in the `RunWorkerCompleted` event:

```
    Me.ResumeLayout()
```

That should suspend all layout logic until all the work is done, then update the entire form in 1 operation.

**EDIT**

Replace

```
BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(...)
```

With

```
DirectCast(sender, BackgroundWorker).ReportProgress(...)
```

And get rid of the synclock.

**EDIT2**

The correct way to feed the data to the `DoWork` event is through the `DoWorkEventArgs`.

Start work like this:

```
BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(<globalvar>)
```

And access it like this:

```
Dim globalVarData As Object = e.Argument
```

Comment: THat's sort of what it's doing now.  Is there a way I could get it to update the controls realtime rather than waiting for all work in the BGW to complete before updating the UI?

Comment: While that might give you the impression that it's running faster, it would actually take longer. By the way I don't see anything in your code snippet that is preventing the layout from updating until the BGW has completed its work.

Comment: Interesting.  Could you elaborate more on that?

As for the code, I don't have anything preventing it from updating.  THe main UI thread goes through its controls and logic, updates the UI all while the BGW's code is getting worked asynchronously however the UI won't update(the BGW controls) until the BGW is complete

Comment: (Re)drawing controls on screen takes time and happens every time you change something on the form (in this case labels). If you have a lot of changing controls, windows will have to do these drawing operations multiple times. Suspending layout logic until all controls are in their final state removes that overhead.

Comment: @Criel I added another suggestion that should improve your code.